# Is it possible to put a background image to a component 'Group' with CSS? How?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, skinning

In a component 'Group' I drag multiple pictures at one time I need to clean this component, but contains a component BitmapImage and I will not be erased:

```
        <s:Group id="droppedImages"  width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:BitmapImage id="bg" source="@Embed('lineal2.jpg')" width="1024" height="577" verticalCenter="0"/>
        </s:Group>
```

I do this:

```
while (droppedImages.numChildren > 0) droppedImages.removeElementAt(0);
```

Im try something like:

```
while (droppedImages.numChildren > 1 ) { 
    if(droppedImages.getChildAt(0).name != 'bg'){
        droppedImages.removeChildAt(0)
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to remove all children from the group?  Or are you trying to remove all children, except the BitMapImage?  Or are you trying to do something else?  Is the problem that the BitMapImage isn't getting removed?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you're confusing "children" and "elements". They are not compatible numbers.

Comment: Hi, i'm  trying to remove all children, except the BitMapImage. Ty.

Comment: I solved in a simply duumy way :)                                 while (droppedImages.numChildren > 1)droppedImages.removeElementAt(1);

Comment: In general, this is a bad practice because the number of children is not always equal to the number of elements. This may work in your specific use case, but don't make it a habit. You should use `numElements` instead of `numChildren`.